# How to execute an action on button click when one code covers all buttons?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a lightweight code for button clicks, so with the help of some people I now have one code that works for all buttons.

What I forgot though, was that how can each button execute unique code such as loading a different page when I use one code for all?

Here's an example of what I have now:
http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/pGmZV/

Thanks for your help everyone :))))

Edit: Each button should load a different page, such as:

```
$('#content').load('SomePage.html', function() {});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the id

```
jQuery(document).delegate(".menuCanBeActive", "click", function( e ) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(".menuCanBeActive").removeClass("menuActive");
    jQuery(this).addClass("menuActive");

    var pageToLoad = '';
    switch( this.id ){
       case 'buttonone':
          pageToLoad = 'aaa.htm';
          break;
       case 'buttontwo':
          pageToLoad = 'bbb.htm';
          break;
       //etc
    }
    if( '' !== pageToLoad ){
       $('#content').load( pageToLoad, function() {});
    }
});
```

Comment: np.. also don't forget to set e.preventDefault(); at the very top

Comment: @fritzfromlondon - you forgot to add "e" as the argument to your event handler.

Answer (score 3):

Add something more meaningful to your href:

```
<a id="buttonone" class="menuCanBeActive" href="one.html"></a><BR>
<a id="buttontwo" class="menuCanBeActive" href="two.html"></a><BR>
<a id="buttonthree" class="menuCanBeActive" href="three.html"></a><BR>
```

Add then use that in your jQuery:

```
jQuery("#buttonone").addClass("menuActive");

//Menu Buttons
jQuery(document).delegate(".menuCanBeActive", "click", function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(".menuCanBeActive").removeClass("menuActive");
    jQuery(this).addClass("menuActive");
    $('#content').load(jQuery(this).attr("href"), function() {});
});
```

Comment: This has the advantage of still doing something useful if javascript is turned off - unobtrusive.

Comment: they ALL do something useful if javascript is turned off, including the one posted in the question. Also, all your code is doing is alerting the href - where is the branching depending on the button being clicked? Lastly, taking clue from the href is a bad idea.

Comment: I didn't bother guessing what his logic needed to be - I figured the alert with the value was enough to get him started.  What exactly does the original version do that is useful, when JS is off?  They all link to empty hash marks, which will do nothing.

Comment: Now that I see OP has changed his question to show that his desired result would be, I have changed the alert code to this more directly-useful (and still unobtrusive) version.

Comment: Should point out that my answer has the other advantage that the function does not need to be modified in order to accomodate new links added to the page.  This was basically requested by OP ("have one code that works for all buttons").

Comment: but you assume that the URL being loaded by the button click is the same the would be loaded if javascript was disabled

Comment: No reason not to assume that.  If there needs to be a different response based on whether it was loaded via AJAX or directly, that could be detected by the server from the presence of the  X-Requested-With request header.

Comment: Hi Jake, Thanks for the answer, I'm sure it'll be useful to me in the future :)))